# Error 403 when loading images from Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I'm working on and Android App that uses quite the sum of images. These images are hosted on Google drive and are loaded through a shareable like (like this one https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1-hEjG3eO0VtZNagUvvppAKk5O39MwrFb).

On this app, I tried using both Glide and Picasso to load the images but Glide only loads some of the images and Picasso either loads them all or doesn't load any (its random). Both of these use OkHttp to get the data and it always returns status 403 when they don't load.

This could be a google issue, but I made a request spammer in python and was always getting code 200, which makes me think the problem is with OkHttp.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Code used with Glide:

```
Glide.with(Context).load(URL).transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade()).into(img);
```

Error returned by Glide:

```
com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: Forbidden, status code: 403
        at com.bumptech.glide.integration.okhttp3.OkHttpStreamFetcher.onResponse(OkHttpStreamFetcher.java:71)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:153)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Code used with Picasso:

```
Picasso.get().load(URL).into(img);
```

Error returned by Picasso:

```
W/System.err: com.squareup.picasso.NetworkRequestHandler$ResponseException: HTTP 403 W/System.err: at com.squareup.picasso.NetworkRequestHandler.load(NetworkRequestHandler.java:51) W/System.err: at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.hunt(BitmapHunter.java:219) W/System.err: at com.squareup.picasso.BitmapHunter.run(BitmapHunter.java:175) W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462) W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) W/System.err: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923) W/System.err: at com.squareup.picasso.Utils$PicassoThread.run(Utils.java:354)
```

Comment: Please share some code.

Comment: @tomerpacific I have edited the post with some examples

Comment: `status code: 403` is a server reply message, not an issue on the code

Comment: I don't know what your request spammer did but gdrive does throttle and limit requests, they don't want people using it as free image hosting

Comment: @Zain But this only happens on my android app. I built a website using these same images and they all load perfectly fine. I also noticed that when loading the URL in a browser, there is a cookie in the request parameters. Could this have anything to do with it?

Comment: @Pawel The spammer was supposed to fetch different images (all from gdrive) repeatedly, simulating a user load.
It is true that they don't want people using it as a free image hosting service, but as long as I respect the bandwidth limits it should be fine right?